# WSLG missing /mnt/wslg folder - How can I get wslg working in Windows Subsystem For Linux?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've exhausted my Google-Fu powers and have come up short. I am trying to get WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) v2 running with the ability to launch wayland or X GUI applications.

WSL itself is running fine, but it seems like it's just ignoring anything to do with WSLG. I've googled and read everything I could find and it seems that the common thread is that everyone has the folder (inside the WSL container) `/mnt/.WSLG` folder. I don't, it's missing.

I've found this reddit thread (https://www.reddit.com/r/wsl2/comments/y7epv4/cant_get_wslg_to_work_in_windows_11_no_mntwslg/) that describes my situation exactly, except he had a config file in `%USERPROFILE%\.wslconfig` that had a line in the `[wsl2]` section which disabled WSLG from loading: `guiApplications = false`. For him, he set that line to be `true` and then life was grand. I didn't have that file, so I created it, and then set that line to be `true` and nothing changed.

I've installed the latest wsl, then did the wsl --update, then installed the special WSL2 update MSI to ensure WSLG is present and available and have set the default version and the VM version to WSL2. I've also installed the recommended drivers for my Intel video card.

Running `wsl --version` only works in an elevated powershell prompt and it returns (which seems good):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --version
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2215
```

Running `wsl -l -v` shows

```
PS C:\Users\sali> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Debian          Stopped         2
  Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
```

If I run that same command in a regular PS prompt it just spits out the help text for `wsl.exe`. Weird, but okay I guess?

I've enabled the debug mode, but there were no relevant entries/errors about wslg or graphics related at all.

I've uninstalled/re-installed/installed from the Microsoft Store, commandline, while standing on one leg, no luck.

I'm running Windows 11 which was upgraded from Windows 10. I've enabled `Virtual Machine Platform` and `Windows Subsystem for Linux` and `Hyper-V`. Still nada.

I found another thread where someone had the same issue (no /mnt/.WSLG directory) but their solution was to apply outstanding Windows updates. I checked, and it says I'm fully up to date. Running `winver` shows `Version 22H2 (OS Build 22621.2215)`

Without the /mnt/.WSLG directory I can't get the other logs that may shed light, though I suspect if I got that far then I wouldn't have an issue.

I can confirm that the wslg.exe application is there, but running it doesn't appear to do anything. It looks like it's meant to execute a Linux X App from the Windows Command Line, I tried to launch `gnome-text-editor` but that didn't appear to do anything. No output and returns to the commandline.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, no wlsg, but I also couldn't update wsl at all (some elevation problem). Found solution from here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9039

Just ran from console with admin rights:
wsl --update --web-download

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the `wsl --update --web-download` command but just had a printout of the help text, nothing else.